# PostgreSQL Query with aggregates and RIGHT JOIN not filtering

Tags: sql, postgresql, outer-join

I have two tables on a one to many map, inventory and lots, on the lots table I have boolean field named deleted, so I don't delete rows for really, but change the flag to be ignored and not count by the query, I am being trying to combined on one query for a view, but if I add the deleted field then the RIGHT JOIN of the query behave like INNER JOIN and I want ALL FROM inventory on the sample below works fine but does not exclude any deleted records on the table jap.lots.

```
    CREATE VIEW view_inventory_lots AS 
SELECT count(lots.*) AS lots,
sum(lots.qty_available) AS available,
sum(lots.qty_received) AS received,
sum(lots.qty_on_hand) AS onhand,
sum(lots.qty_allocated) AS allocated,
inventories.* 
FROM jap.lots RIGHT JOIN jap.inventories
 ON jap.lots.inventory_id = jap.inventories.inventory_id
  GROUP BY inventories.inventory_id;
```

If I try to modify this view to add the lot.deleted field for filtering with the query below:

```
SELECT count(lots.*) AS lots,
sum(lots.qty_available) AS available,
sum(lots.qty_received) AS received,
sum(lots.qty_on_hand) AS onhand,
sum(lots.qty_allocated) AS allocated,
lots.deleted,
inventories.* 
FROM jap.lots RIGHT JOIN jap.inventories
 ON jap.lots.inventory_id = jap.inventories.inventory_id
 WHERE lots.deleted = false
  GROUP BY inventories.inventory_id, lots.deleted;
```

The result is only the inventory rows that have records on lots table, so the purpose of the RIGHT JOIN is ignored, behaving as  INNER JOIN

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Common convention is to name tables by the singular of a row's identity not the plural.  In this way lots => lot and inventories => inventory

Comment: Hogan - you are right regarding the tables names, but this is a failed project on my side done using Mongodb, originally mongo named that way, so I keep the naming for that reason

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a column from the "outer" table in the `where` clause turns the outer join into an inner join. Move the condition on that table into the `join` condition:

```
FROM jap.lots 
  RIGHT JOIN jap.inventories 
     ON jap.lots.inventory_id = ap.inventories.inventory_id
    AND lots.deleted = false
GROUP BY ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I find `left join`s much easier to follow -- keep all rows in the *first* table and matching rows in the rest.  Your problem is that the condition in the `where` clause undoes the outer join.

I would write this as:

```
SELECT count(l.*) AS lots,
       sum(l.qty_available) AS available,
       sum(l.qty_received) AS received,
       sum(l.qty_on_hand) AS onhand,
       sum(l.qty_allocated) AS allocated,
       l.deleted,
       i.* 
FROM jap.inventories i LEFT JOIN
     jap.lots l LEFT JOIN 
     ON l.inventory_id = i.inventory_id AND
        l.deleted = false
GROUP BY i.inventory_id, l.deleted;
```

Also notice the use of table aliases and qualified column names.  These make the query easier to write and to read.  Also, they make it more consistent: your use of table names was inconsistent throughout the query.